# Ember select and query parameters. Getting undefined

Tags: select, ember.js, undefined

I'm trying to select an option, and once it's selected, get the value of the object and change the url with that value.

right now, I'm getting undefined in the url:

```
http://localhost:4200/product?company=undefined
```

controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   queryParams: ['company'],
   company: null,
    .......

   actions: {
     selectCompany: function(value) {
     this.set('company', value);
      }
    }

 });
```

Template:

```
<select {{ action 'selectCompany' company.id on='change' }}>
    {{#each sortedTraitsAsc as |company|}}
       <option value={{company.id}}>  {{company.value}}</option>
   {{/each}}
 </select>
```

Model

```
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('string')
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, for the option tag, you also need to supply the selected value to let the controller know what the selection is.

Here's a working sample that I recreated based on an assumption of what you're trying to do.

Before continuing ... make sure that you install Ember Truth Helpers - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers by running the following Ember CLI command:

```
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

Your route (to supply the model in this case) will look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return [{'name': 'a', 'valuation': 100},
            {'name': 'b', 'valuation': 200},
            {'name': 'c', 'valuation': 150},
            {'name': 'd', 'valuation': 250}
          ];
  }
});
```

Your controller looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['company'],
  company: null,
  actions: {
    selectCompany: function(company){
        alert(company);
        this.set('company', company);
      }
}});
```

And your template looks like this:

```
<select onchange={{action "selectCompany" value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each model as |companyChoice|}}
    <option value={{companyChoice.name}} selected={{eq company companyChoice.name}}>{{companyChoice.name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I think I'm starting to understand better how it works, I'm still getting undefined. I think the issue may be in value and the selected section :(